# Nupkg not reading baseversion from gitinfo.txt

Tags: .net, git, nuget, semantic-versioning

I am building a package using nuget and facing issues with the versioning of the package. I have defined base version to be 1.0.10 in the gitinfo file but it is creating the pkg with 1.0.5 version. How do I force it to use 1.0.10 as base version?

Comment: For others: GitInfo is https://github.com/kzu/GitInfo

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using a version string constants composed with:

`Git.BaseVersion.Major` + "." +
`Git.BaseVersion.Minor` + "." +
`Git.BaseVersion.Commits`

instead of:

`Git.BaseVersion.Major` + "." +
`Git.BaseVersion.Minor` + "." +
`Git.BaseVersion.Patch`